# How to make TextField label text with top padding?

Tags: flutter, textfield

I want to make label text with padding on top like in this image:

[image: what needed]

What I do:

```
TextField(
            controller: emailTextController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: Dimens.textFieldBorderRadius,
                ),
                filled: true,
                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontFamily: 'SFPro',
                  height: 7.0,
                ),
                labelText: Strings.enterEmail,
                fillColor: Colors.white70),
          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using stack widget to prioritize TextFiled over label Text.

**Result**

[image]

**Widget**

```dart
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: kTextTabBarHeight * 1.2, // play with it
                width: constraints.maxWidth,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                ),
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    /// sort based on tapPriority
                    Positioned(
                      top: 8,
                      left: 8,
                      child: Text(
                        "Password",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 12,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      bottom: 0,
                      left: 8,
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: constraints.maxWidth * .9,
                        child: TextField(
                          obscureText: true,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 6)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                    /// Play with condition here
                    Positioned(
                      top: 0,
                      bottom: 0,
                      right: 8,
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.check,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```